# How to optimize particles with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating particles for the first time with javascript and I'm not sure if the below code is optimized.

When I create 100 particles on the screen I don't notice that much of an fps drop.

When multiple clicks happen in a row the fps takes major dip.

This is understandable but is there a way to optimize this code more so that multiple clicks will maintain a higher frame rate?

```js
var fps = document.getElementById("fps");
var startTime = Date.now();
var frame = 0;

function tick() {
  var time = Date.now();
  frame++;
  if (time - startTime > 1000) {
      fps.innerHTML = (frame / ((time - startTime) / 1000)).toFixed(1);
      startTime = time;
      frame = 0;
    }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}
tick();

function pop (target) {
  let amount = 100;
  // Quick check if user clicked the button using a keyboard
    const bbox = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = bbox.left + bbox.width / 2;
    const y = bbox.top + bbox.height / 2;
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

      createParticle(x, y);
    }
  
  
}
function createParticle (x, y) {
  const particle = document.createElement('particle');
  document.body.appendChild(particle);
  let width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 8);
  let height = width;
  let destinationX = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000;
  let destinationY = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000;
  let rotation = Math.random() * 2000;
  let delay = Math.random() * 200;

      particle.style.background = `hsl(${Math.random() * 90 + 270}, 70%, 60%)`;
      particle.style.border = '1px solid white';
  
  particle.style.width = `${width}px`;
  particle.style.height = `${height}px`;
  const animation = particle.animate([
    {
      transform: `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${x}px, ${y}px) rotate(0deg)`,
      opacity: 1
    },
    {
      transform: `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${x + destinationX}px, ${y + destinationY}px) rotate(${rotation}deg)`,
      opacity: 0
    }
  ], {
    duration: Math.random() * 1000 + 5000,
    easing: 'cubic-bezier(0, .9, .57, 1)',
    delay: delay
  });
  animation.onfinish = removeParticle;
}
function removeParticle (e) {
  e.srcElement.effect.target.remove();
}
document.querySelector(".confetti").addEventListener("click",()=>{pop(document.querySelector(".confetti"));}
);
```

```css
particle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="fps">--</span> FPS</div>
  <div class="confetti">Square particles</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You might need to debounce the clicks so it only actually causes an action at a given time interval. If the user smashes the mouse key it shouldn't get to the point where its creating 100's of shapes and slowing everything down. Maybe also it might be more efficient to use something like canvas, so you can control the updates.

Comment: Consider posting this to [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

It would be much quicker if you could add a canvas and instead of adding the elements and styling them, you could just draw things onto the canvas. Then, it can be way faster. If you don't get how to use a canvas with JavaScript, you might want to search it up on something like W3Schools, because they have lots of things you could learn from them.

I hope this helps. Please give me any feedback if you have any. I am new to Stack Overflow, so I want to know how to improve. Thanks and happy coding!